# [angular 4 / typescript ]import component path not reconized. But seems valid and should work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, import

I am building a router component in angular and typescript.

observe my current project structure below. 
[image]

Lets focus on the landingPageComponent

observe by the image that my path to the component is valid but is not recognized.

my code in my landingpageComponent.ts file:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landingpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landingpage.component.css']
})
export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('f')citySubmit : NgForm;

  cities:string[]=['Chicago', 'New Mexico', 'London'];

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

the proper imports are done in the app.module.ts file without error. Meaning the path is recognized.

I am hoping I am just making a silly mistake somewhere

Thank you.

Comment: What is the import path if you go into `app.module.ts`?

Comment: import { LandingPageComponent } from './landingpage/landingpage.component';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app.routing.module.ts it should be,

```
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landingpage/landingpage.component';
import { HowItWorksComponent } from './howitworks/howitworks.component'
```

Comment: no significant change from what I had the problem persists

Comment: did you change as above

Comment: i did. fixed the " to ' and removed the second ; with no change.

Comment: same as before. No change. Error code is following:

TS2307: cannot find module

Comment: cannot find which module?

Comment: both the landingpagecomponent and howitworkscomponent